# Anyone want to contribute a blog-post?

Tags: discussion, community-blog

[Here](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1FqdpiJSEy5gUq455Pjp6ge-lTwb3ykLgKN6fH7yOH-U/) is the schedule of blog-posts.  If anyone is interested in contributing a blog-post, I would like to suggest that they check out the schedule, and if they see a subject they wish to write on (that a subject that hasn't been written on before), then give an answer under this meta post mentioning the subject in it.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to participate. But the time is not enough to do a research for the upcoming topic. Wish I could come op with a good one!